# Implementing SSO using Okta

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

I have a MVC web application that needs to be authenticated against Okta (the users will be stored in Okta). I have some third party applications to which my customers will navigate through their links in my website. The customers, once they are authenticated while coming to my page should not have to be authenticated again when they navigate to these third party links.

I also have have some third party web sites consuming my external exposed web services (MVC Web APIs). These third party applications are also expected to authenticate themselves through Okta.

How can I implement these two scenarios? I know how to implement the customer authentication by Okta using their APIs, but the part not clear is how to enable the seamless navigation between the third party websites.

Comment: Hello Thomas, I suggest you take at our fresh off the oven ASP.NET / OpenID Connect sample at https://github.com/rlondner/okta-aspnet-spa_webapi-oidc . Would that help?